# Is there a way to open the file explorer and return a user selected file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm building a Flask back-end with a get method that returns an excel file in JSON format. The code I have so far is:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,' + str('C:/Users/'))
    elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
        subprocess.Popen(["open", 'C:/Users/'])
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", 'C:/Users/'])
    milestones = pd.read_excel('USER SELECTED FILE FROM FILE EXPLORER.xlsx').to_json()
    return milestones
```

However, subprocess.popen only allows for the opening of the file explorer and does not allow the return of the file the user selects. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You'll probably have to use a GUI library.

Answer (score 1):

Why not provide the complete filepath as such-

```
import pandas as pd
milestones = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jack/Desktop/your_file.xlsx').to_json
```

Or

```
# you can change your directory to the specified one
# and then load into a DataFrame
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir("/Users/Jack/Desktop")
milestones = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx').to_json
```

Comment: Because I need to allow the user to select the excel file they would like to extract.

Comment: Okay, if it is not a front-end requirement, can you ask the user to enter the filename? file_name = input('Please Enter the Excel File'), you can also put this into a while loop which checks whether the provided input is accepted or not.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies. I'm making the request from React, so I'm just going to handle the file upload via js on the front-end. I may have just misinterpreted the project instructions because I think the only way to achieve what I'm trying to do is with a gui and I don't think the assignment would ask me to do that.